# Set text value of Text game object to a certain key when it is pressed (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two buttons, and each button has a Text game object that is a child to it. When a button is pressed and a key is then pressed after, I want to update the text shown by the Text game object that is a child to the button that was pressed. Here's what I tried:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    Event currentEvent = Event.current;
    if (currentEvent.isKey)
    {
        if (currentEvent.keyCode.ToString() != "None")
        {
            keyboardEvent = currentEvent;
            key = keyboardEvent.keyCode.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public void changeFirstKey()
{
    if (keyboardEvent.isKey)
    {
        firstKeyText.text = key;
    }
}

public void changeSecondKey()
{
    if (keyboardEvent.isKey)
    {
        secondKeyText.text = key;
    }
}
```

The first button is called `firstKey` and the second is called `secondKey`. I made sure that when `firstKey` is clicked it calls `changeFirstKey` and vice versa for `secondKey`. However, the text shown doesn't change. It throws an error in the console every time I try to click on one of the buttons, and the problem is that `keyboardEvent` is not set to an instance of an object. I made sure that `keyboardEvent` was a global variable so i could access it outside of `OnGUI` but i still get this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger and putting a breakpoint inside `OnGUI` to see when it is hit and what happens?

Comment: @UnholySheep If you mean to check the value of `keyboardEvent` or `key`, i did that. `keyboardEvent.keyCode.ToString()` does return the key that i pressed, but only when i call it inside of `OnGUI` (and the same for `key`).

Comment: Based on the code shown, it seems like that OnGUI has not been called.  If you test keyboardEvent in both change functions for null before using .isKey you'll see that keyboardEvent hasn't been set.

Comment: @Displayname when i test `keyboardEvent` in `OnGUI`, it isn't null. When i test it in either of the change functions, it is. However, `keyboardEvent` is a public variable i declared outside of `OnGUI`, so i'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Since C# doesn't have globals I assume you are using something like this static class which has a static member. 
    public static class MyValues
    {
        public static Event currentEvent { get; set}
    }

Comment: Would you show where you have `keyboardEvent` declared? Having the scope information available in the question is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of this:

- Using caps in KeyCode:

`keyboardEvent.KeyCode.ToString()`

- Try to debug 'currentEvent' to see the result

  Debug.Log(currentEvent)
- Read this post of unity manual [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your changeFirstKey changeSecondKey is Button Method right? How will Satisfy if

(keyboardEvent.isKey)(); When you press Button?

This is a One way of implementation you have attach this script to Buttons.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


    public class MyTestClass : MonoBehaviour,IPointerExitHandler,IPointerDownHandler
    {


        bool _isFirstButtonPressed = false;
        bool _isSecondButtonPressed = false;

        Event keyboardEvent = new Event();

        public Text firstKeyText;
        public Text secondKeyText;
        private string key;

        public Button _button;









        public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
        {

            if (eventData.selectedObject.name == "FirstButton")
            {
                _isFirstButtonPressed = true;
            }

            if (this.gameObject.name == "SecondButton")
            {
                _isSecondButtonPressed = true;
            }

        }

        public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            if (this.gameObject.name == "FirstButton")
            {
                _isFirstButtonPressed = false;
            }

            if (this.gameObject.name == "SecondButton")
            {
                _isSecondButtonPressed = false;
            }
        }



        void OnGUI()
            {
                Event currentEvent = Event.current;

            if (currentEvent.isKey)
                {

                if (currentEvent.keyCode.ToString() != "None")
                    {
                        keyboardEvent = currentEvent;
                        key = keyboardEvent.keyCode.ToString();


                    if (_isFirstButtonPressed) {
                        firstKeyText.text = key;
                    }

                    if (_isSecondButtonPressed)
                    {
                        secondKeyText.text = key;
                    }

                }
                }
            }
```